# instantiateViewController problem after the app passes the face id and the touch id authentication

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode10

I have added a "touch id or face id" button in my page. I have created an action for this button: `btnTouchIdOrFaceIdIsPressed`. Question 1: It does not open the `HomePageViewController` in the app screen after I click on `touch id or face` id button. Why?

```
@IBAction func btnTouchIdOrFaceIdIsPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.useBiometricAuthentication()
}

func useBiometricAuthentication () {
    let context = LAContext()
    var error : NSError?
    let reason = "some message for app user for the touch id or face id.."
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) { (success, error) in
            if success {
                self.callMeAfterSuccessLoginAction()
            } else {
                //Question2: Can you write an explanation for this scope? Touch id or face is authentication is failed, right?
            }
        }
    } else {
        //Question3: Can you write an explanation for this scope? "device does not support face id or touch id", right?
    }
}

func callMeAfterSuccessLoginAction() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let oHomepageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Homepage") as! HomepageViewController
        self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([oHomepageViewController], animated: true)
    }
}
```

Can you also reply question 2 and question 3 please?

Comment: Please check if it's coming into `success` condition i.e. `callMeAfterSuccessLoginAction` is getting called. If so then check if your `navigationController` is not nil

Comment: I put print in to callMeAfterSucessLoginAction. I see print. But i have solved with another way. I have created one function. I wrote performsegue in to this function. And then i have called this function in DispatchQueue.main.async in callMeAfterSucessLoginAction. It worked. I see homepage view controller. Thanks for the reply. Can you give an explanation for the Scope2 and Scope 3 if it is possible? (question2 and question3) Or can you say my comments are correct? or missing? @ArnabHore

Comment: And Dear @ArnabHore can you write how can i check navigationController is not nil. Can you share that code please?

Comment: Dear, @ArnabHore I have checked, yes, navigationController is nil. What should i write to see homepage after callMeAfterSuccessLoginAction method is executed?

Comment: That's probably because your current ViewController may be presented modally. In that case dismiss the ViewController and then push from navigation controller. Or move to root navigation controller, then push to HomeViewController.

Comment: Another way is to present HomeController, but that's not what you wanted I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question1: It does not open the HomePageViewController in the app
>   screen after I click on touch id or face id button. Why?

You can check if your navigationController is not nil

```
print(navigationController ?? "NavigationController is nil")
```

> Question2: Can you write an explanation for this scope? Touch id or face is authentication is failed, right?

Touch ID or face ID authentication is failed

> Question3: Can you write an explanation for this scope? "device does not support face id or touch id", right?

Touch ID or FaceID authentication is unavailable, may be user does not set it